# linux command line running java program connect to db2

Tags: java, linux

I have a java program that connects to a DB2 database and do some cleanning, it's working fine from eclipse, however, I want to put it to my server's crontab, so that it can run automatically every other week

here is the essential command I use for eclipse

```
java -cp /some/path/my/jar/files -connectionUrl jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/STATS other_argument
```

(I have STATS database on the same machine) It works for eclipse

however, When I run this command line in Linux, it gives me such error

```
ERROR: [PacketDispatcher.cpp:100] Run: Exception in connection: TransportException [510/202] connection failed (error code: -249)
```

I am wondering if it is because I cannot use jdbc directly from command line or are there any other problem with it.

Please, help, any answer will be appreciated

Comment: I don't think java do what you think it does with `-connectionUrl ...` also you'are missing a main class on your command line

Comment: Are you sure your connection URL is correct? The default port for DB2 is normally 50000, not 5000

Comment: @Lolo oh, sorry, you are right, I mistyped, it is 50000,

Comment: @RC -connectionUrl is just one argument my java program needs to connect to the database